# What is the abbreviation for this site

Tags: discussion, name

SPO?

Or would that clash with SharePoint Online

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPO

Comment: SharePoint Online is abbrevated as SPOL when i see it

Answer (score 4):

Right now I'd argue that since migration the site doesn't even have a name yet, or that it is called "SharePoint Stack Exchange". So you could base your abbreviation on that, e.g. SPSE.

However we do need to decide on a name. We can continue to call it SharePoint Overflow if we want, or come up with a new name more people prefer. (This is loosely covered under point 4 in [The 7 Essential Meta Questions of Every Beta](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/) and should be discussed in a new meta question.)

Comment: So does that mean the URL can/will change once we go out of beta?

Comment: @Anders: Yes, if we have or can get the domain name.

Comment: I've been using SP.SE (because of the URL), but I like SharePoint Overflow better.

Comment: "SharePoint Overflow" is good

Comment: Twitter gibber: #SPSE is free, #SPOverflow is quiet, #Spose is full of trash.

Comment: @KitMenke, @moontear: Let's get our [elevator pitch](http://meta.sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/76/whats-the-elevator-pitch-for-our-site) done and we'll be able to sort out the title.

Answer (score 4):

Expanding on Alex's answer:

SharePoint On Stack Exchange? SPOSE, pronounced Spose.

Being easy to say would be a boon.

Comment: I 'spose so....