# What’s the “elevator pitch” for our site?

Tags: discussion, 7-essential-questions

From [**The 7 Essential Meta Questions of Every Beta**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/):

> Imagine you've just gotten on an
>   elevator with a friendly stranger. You
>   have precisely one floor to describe
>   your community to them. What would you
>   say? The elevator pitch is a brief
>   sentence that describes *what your
>   site is about*.

This question will help lead us to our site name, [abbreviation](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59/what-is-the-abbreviation-for-this-site), tagline, etc... and is one of the essential questions that will help us complete beta and launch! (Here's [some ideas](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/stack-exchange-naming-for-dummies/).)

So, in a few words, **describe our site**!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We are a global community of SharePoint enthusiasts helping each other to overcome real world SharePoint challenges.

Comment: +1, I like this one.. A nitpick may be to remove "worldwide". Or replace it with something like "global" so we don't use "world" twice.

Comment: Yep good point - thanks :)

Comment: +1, I like this as well.

Comment: Right on the money, couldnt have said it better myself :)

Comment: Covers the reasons I come to the site

Comment: Not sure about "enthusiasts". Sounds like we are amateurs. How about "experts"? Maybe that's too far the other way. How about "experts and enthusiasts" or "enthusiasts and professionals".

Answer (score 1):

Answers for SharePoint from the people of SharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

Rage against the SharePoint? Answers are just a question away.

Comment: Or more commonly known as `RatS`.

Comment: @Kit: Rage against the SharePoint? Ask Really Sympathetic Experts.

Comment: haha, thats pro

Comment: Oh please... I for once dont like the underlying allusion here. We all know the product isnt perfect, but we of all should be beyond any SharePoint battering. For me its simple: I use this site because I love SharePoint, not to try and do any evangelism or anyting, people should be able to decide for themselves if they are up to the challenge of working with this product. Ps sorry about the rant :)

Comment: @Anders: We kid because we love.

Answer (score 0):

SP Overflow: We have all the answers for SharePoint.