# What is the name of this site?

Tags: discussion, name

The prequel to this post: [What is the abbreviation for this site](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59/what-is-the-abbreviation-for-this-site) (the prequel is released after, just like in the movies!)

What should the name of the site be? For reference, [here is the list of current sites](http://stackexchange.com/sites).

Please put one name per answer so they can be voted up/down.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't see why SharePoint Stack Exchange wouldn't be your first and best choice... I mean, **that's what it is!** System-specific Q&A. It's not like you need to stand out from all those *other* SharePoint Stack Exchange sites... You are **the one**.

In a comment, Anders notes the desire to link the site to Stack Overflow - well, the "stack" part of Stack Exchange is intended to do just that! It's a bit weird to stop and think about how many SE 1.0 sites chose an "Overflow" suffix for their names, given that the important part of the SO double entendre, the bit these sites are set up to *help*, is the *mental stack*...

Anyway, this site *has* been SP.SE for the entire beta, and now that the design work is underway the branding is gonna continue to focus on **SharePoint** and **Stack Exchange**. If you'd like to see [a tongue-in-cheek nautical theme](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/361/what-is-the-name-of-this-site/363#363), suggest it [here](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364/site-design-ideas)... ;-)

Answer (score 4):

SharePoint on Stack Exchange abbreviates nicely (alluding to the sequel): SPSE.

Comment: S.O.S. -> SharePoint on StackExchange

Comment: As specified [here](http://meta.sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/59/what-is-the-abbreviation-for-this-site/60#60) we are not locked by URL or name to keep StackExhange, so why not keep our "old" name, url and abbreviation SPO?

Comment: @Kit: Haha! "SharePoint SOS" has a ring to it...

Comment: @Anders: Migrating the site is a good opportunity to reconsider our options; some mischief in the status quo to make us see the norm in a new light. Perhaps you should add to your answer why we *should* keep the old name, so we can see the merits of such a choice.

Comment: @Kit: Doh! Taken. :/

Answer (score 0):

Why SharePoint Overflow of course :)

Comment: I call it this out loud, but write it "SPSE"...

Comment: I'm not a fan of this name because it piggybacks off Stack Overflow rather than giving us our own identity. On the flip side it's what the community is familiar with. Oh, and I can't think of anything better right now...!

Comment: I rather like the fact that there is a link to both SharePoint and Stack Overflow. You could call it piggybacking, but it just seem foolish to throw away all the reputation that goes with both the brand name SPO, and our big brother SO. In the years we have worked up a considerable brand value, so why change that now?

Comment: SharePoint Overflow is the name that ppl will talk about, ppl are talking about and ppl have been talking about. Why invent something new if we got something that already works!?