# New Design Launched

Tags: discussion, design

As you can see the new design just went live. Which means this site has been officially launched! Congratulations! Thank you for your valuable [design feedback](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/390/design-for-sharepoint-stack-exchange).

If you're still seeing the old favicons, please load the follow urls and do a hard browser refresh.

http://sstatic.net/sharepoint/img/favicon.ico

http://sstatic.net/sharepointmeta/img/favicon.ico

We have also themed the [chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/411/sharepoint), [twitter](http://twitter.com/#!/stacksharepoint) account and newsletter template for this site.

If you see any CSS/styling bugs, please start a new post and tag it with "design" and "bug."

Congrats on the launch and thank you for being an awesome community!

Comment: Ooooh... Nice. :)

Comment: Very, very nice.

Comment: I like it....very nice.  Glad to see the site has officially launched as well!

Answer (score 4):

OMG It's Alive!!!

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xos2MnVxe-c

Answer (score 3):

whoaaaaa!!!! The design.... Love it!

**EDIT:**

I find some of the fonts are hard to read especially with the lighter colors :)

**EDIT 2:**

Attached a screenshot. I'm not sure if it has something to do with my eyes lol but I find the word StackExchange a little dark for me but it doesn't bother me at all because I can still read it.

Second is the font size of the links below when I click on the StackExchange dropdown. I find it a hard to read, It might be on my browser (Firefox 6.0.2) although I could still read it when I hold down ctrl + mouse roller up so I could see the font bigger.

It's not really a big deal thing, I'm just looking around for something that I feel I could contribute at least :)

[image]

Comment: I would recommend including an example of where you find it hard to read so that @Jin can take a look. A screenshot might help too.

Comment: @Rash I'll be spending the next few days correcting some styling bugs. meanwhile, feel free to report any issues you see. Thanks!

Comment: @kit uploaded screenshots :) hope it helps :)

Answer (score 2):

Looking good :) even the shortcut on my iPad has changed to new logo :)

Answer (score 1):

Awesome! That was a QUICK turn around! It will take a little getting used to, but I definitely like it a lot more than the scratch paper theme!

Answer (score 1):

Good Job Everyone!!  Keep up the participation.

Answer (score 0):

It looks cool but it is very hard on the eyes. I recommend making major changes to the thread title font/color or background color or you will see a decline in users. If you need hints on why its hard to read I'd suggest to start with this: The background is darker blue and the thread titles are lighter blue. This does not make for good readability.

Comment: I'll be tweaking some contrasts. But I disagree with your argument. The title colors against its light background is 3.56, above the AA compliance of 3.10 for larger text. The site's dark blue background color has nothing to do with this. That's your personal preference.

Comment: I guess, just telling you. I'm the second person out of very few respondents who has mentioned difficulty reading.

Answer (score 0):

The site has a very polished look, much better than the "draft" version.

Comment: By the way, is there a link to your profile from the home page? I thought there was a link on the old design.